# How do i list files in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:io';
Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0');
List<FileSystemEntity> file = dir.listSync();
```

I had used that code to list file which only list directory. How can i get list of files in that directory? And how to find permission of files/folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[listSync](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory/listSync.html) method lists both directories and files. If you need only files, you can filter the output:

```dart
dir.listSync().where((e) => e is File);
```

If you need to list files recursively in sub-directories, you can call it with `recursive` parameter:

```dart
dir.listSync(recursive: true).where((e) => e is File);
```

> And how to find permission of files/folder?

```dart
dir.listSync().forEach((e) {
  final mode = e.statSync().mode;
});
```

[mode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/FileStat/mode.html) contains the mode of the file system object.

Permissions are encoded in the lower 16 bits of this number, and can be decoded using the [modeString](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/FileStat/modeString.html) getter.